# AWS Codedeploy running out of space on EC2 instance, How to cleanup deployed Archives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Codedeploy setup which we currently have is running out of space, Now we have to manually delete the archives at location /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/.

How can we clean up the archives regularly? I thought codedploy agent should take care of Archives.

Comment: Use cronjob for removing files on instance

*/30 * * * * cd /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/ && sudo rm -rf *

it will run every 30 minutes

Comment: Configure max_revisions, per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html#codedeploy-agent-revisions-logs-cleanup.

Comment: @RohitDalal Every 30 minutes is way more than you could possibly need, and you are likely to delete something while it's being installed. Run it once a day at most.